# How to add a column in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql

I’m doing a query that extract data from two tables. The thing that I want to do that for a condition that I will put in the “where” expression, if it is correct I want to add a column in my query result in which I will put per example 1 and 0 in the other case. For more details there the form of the result that I want

```
A | B | C | D (new column)
```

So anyone have an idea?

Comment: Sorry to say, it's not clear what you need. Can you provide a specific example of inputs and outputs, and maybe an attempt at the query?

Comment: you can use CASE statement in place of conditional column 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html instead of providing the condition in WHERE clause

Comment: Use `case` in the select clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `case` statement.  Your question is remarkably sparse on details, but the structure of the query looks like:

```
select <whatever>,
       (case when <your condition here> then 1 else 0 end) as Flag
from table1 t1 join
     table2
     on . . .;
```